# Add(T object) Is Not a Contract Method Of IEnumerable<T> -- Why?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

It struck me as weird that any class that inherits from `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't need to implement `Add(T object)`, even though if you want to use [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) when initializing the class instance, you have to implement `Add(T object)`.

Why this is so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface - it's only meant to represent "a sequence".

Collection initializers require `Add` in order to work, but they check that the type implements `IEnumerable` first to make sure it really is a collection type of some description. They don't require the generic form as that would be restrictive for some pre-2.0 code (in particular various UI collections don't implement `IEnumerable<T>` IIRC) and they don't require a *specific* `Add` signature as collection initializers can be used with different numbers of arguments. For example, `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has `Add(TKey value, TValue value)` so you can use:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "Jon", 33 },
    { "Tom", 6 }
};
```

That means it can't be restricted to (say) `IList` which only has the single-argumnet `Add` method. It needs duck typing to some extent, but the `IEnumerable` requirement is an attempt to make sure that `Add` really means "add an item to the collection" rather than something completely different. The compiler doesn't *use* the fact that it implements `IEnumerable` - it never calls `GetEnumerator` when building the collection, for example.

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth here: http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2006/10/10/What-is-a-collection_3F00_.aspx

Comment: It's worth noting that `foreach` does use duck typing on `IEnumerable`, so it is possible to iterate over something using `foreach` without being able to use collection initializers on it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, `IEnumerable` is a read-only interface indicating that a sequence can be iterated, nothing more.

Your wider question about why collection initialisers require the combination of `IEnumerable` and an `Add` method is probably [best addressed by Mads Torgersen](http://blogs.msdn.com/madst/archive/2006/10/10/What-is-a-collection_3F00_.aspx):

> **What is a collection?**
>
> What did we find then? Only 14 of our
>   own (public) classes (with public
>   constructors) implement
>   `ICollection<T>`! Obviously there are a
>   lot more collections in the framework,
>   so it was clear that we needed some
>   other way of telling whether something
>   is a collection class. LINQ to the
>   rescue once more: With modified
>   versions of the query it was easy to
>   establish that among our public
>   classes with public constructors there
>   are:
>
> - 189 that have a public `Add`
>     method and implement
>     `System.Collections.IEnumerable`
> - 42 that have a public `Add`
>     method but do not implement
>     `System.Collections.IEnumerable`
>
> If you look at the classes returned by
>   these two queries, you realize that
>   there are essentially two
>   fundamentally different meanings of
>   the name “Add”:
>
> a)     Insert the argument into a
>   collection, or
>
> b)     Return the arithmetic sum of
>   the argument and the receiver.
>
> People are actually very good at
>   (directly or indirectly) implementing
>   the nongeneric `IEnumerable` interface
>   when writing collection classes, so
>   that turns out to be a pretty reliable
>   indicator of whether an `Add` method is
>   the first or the second kind. Thus for
>   our purposes the operational answer to
>   the headline question becomes:
>
> *A collection is a type that implements
>   `IEnumerable` and has a public `Add`
>   method*

Answer (score 0):

Because `IEnumerable<T>` is an interface for **enumerating** a collection, nothing else.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx):

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports
>   a simple iteration over a collection
>   of a specified type.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable is the bottom of the pile when it comes to "lists" it has the bare basics needed to enumerate over the list, which makes it read only functions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the biggest reason is that not all collections have to be Enumerable.  Also, the fact that you could have other items that are enumerable that are say calculations or some other process.

For example you could use IEnumerable with a Yield command to calculate out prime numbers or the fibonacci sequence.  It's really up to you.

As to the collection initializers since you are working with a collection I am assuming that maybe the initializers are using something akin to the Yield command so it uses IEnumerable to yield up your initialized values to the Add method.

My two cents.

Comment: A more compelling reason is that not all enumerables need to be collections.